# Which algorithms can be used for generating timetables/schedules?

Tags: algorithm, schedule, timetable

I have a question about scheduling.
I need to make a timetable generator for appointments.
this is the current situation.

P1 has an appointment A with P2.

P3 has an appointment B with P4.

and so on...

Appointment A takes about 15 minutes

Appointment B takes about 40 minutes

(The time of duration depends on the number of topics, 1 topic = 5 minutes)

I need to put this into a timetable with a few other constraints, with a limited amount to schedule all the meetings.

My question is: Which algorithms can be used for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the metrics/constraints? I can put exactly one appointment for each day at noon - but I doubt that it is what you are actually looking for.

Comment: This is for 2 days at morning(09.00-13.00) and noon(13.00-16.00).
I just need to know what to study to get this problem solved

Comment: Can you give a little more context about where did the problem come from? I am afraid that even if the "meetings" will need only one person per meeting - you got yourself a [bin-packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), which is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), and adding the 2 people per meeting constraint only makes things harder.

Comment: It's similar to making a schedule for fast-dating events. Only the participants have already made an appointment beforehand

Comment: If there are not many constraints, these sort of problems can often be solved very quickly with an integer programming solver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should look into, as long as the dataset is small, is a classic `backtracking algorithm`, which will solve the problem by bruteforcing. However, the algorithm will get inefficient, if your dataset is growing. In that case, you should have a look at `artificial intelligence` like `genetic algorithms` to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks I think I will base my research on using genetic algorithms to solve this problem. There are in total 6 constraints so I don't know a classic algorithm will solve it. Although the forward state space search is used for airplanes schedules which is similar to my problem.

Comment: Genetic Algorithms would be the most promising and with 6 constraints, you'll hit the limit for backtracking pretty fast (especially if your solution space is very narrow) - same is true for forward space search. The good thing is, that you can implement Backtracking as a decision tree and buffer the state to account for variations. I guess genetic algorithms are the way to go here, too.